# PHP 7: Function which creates different classes with "new class"

Tags: php-7

If I create a class with PHP7 multiple times, it seems it is returning always the same class instead of returning a new one each time.

For example:

```
function createAClass()
{
    return new class
    {
        public static $foo=0;
    };

}

$class = createAClass();
$class::$foo = 3;
echo "class:".$class::$foo."<br>";

$anotherClass = createAClass();
echo "anotherClass:".$anotherClass::$foo."<br>";
```

This is the output:

```
class:3
anotherClass:3
```

I though the output should be 3 and 0. What's happening? Is this a bug, or a "feature" of PHP 7? :)

btw, I was trying to use this to test a trait with static methods with PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the documentation and it seems it is the expected behaviour:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

> All objects created by the same anonymous class declaration are instances of that very class.

But I needed to create a function which returned a different class each time it was called, so I came with this solution:

```
function createAClass()
{
    $class = null;
    $stamp = random_int(PHP_INT_MIN ,PHP_INT_MAX);
    echo "stamp: $stamp\n";
    $classcode = <<< EOT
\$class = new class {
    public static \$differentiate='$stamp';
    // YOUR CODE HERE
};
EOT;
    echo "Source code of class:\n$classcode\n\n";
    eval($classcode);
    return $class;
}

$class = createAClass();
$anotherClass = createAClass();

if (get_class($class) === get_class($anotherClass)) {
    echo 'same class';
} else {
    echo 'different class';
}
```